How do I access config values from app settings in the same method in ASP.NET Core?
I have this simple code for loading app config in an ASP.NET Core site.
I need to use some values from settings in the same method, but how can I access app config data?
_ = builder.Services
    .AddOptions<AssetsOptions>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(AssetsOptions.SectioName))
    .Validate(config =>
    {
        return config.AppId > 0;
    }, "Option AppId must be configured in config section")
    .ValidateOnStart();

For Example:
_ = builder.Services
.AddLog(config.Id)


As you're still building it, might it be simplest to do a manual bind var config = new AssetsOptions(); builder.Configuration.GetSection(AssetsOptions.SectioName).Bind(config); ?

@flackoverstow great solution! thanks

Read values from the configuration
You can access values from the configuration (IConfiguration) directly by querying builder.Configuration.
var appId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<int>("AppSettings:AppId");

var assetsOptions = builder.Configuration.GetSection(AssetsOptions.SectioName).Get<AssetsOptions>();

Use these values in your service registration
builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
{
    loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
    loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
});

// Example: Access AppId in your custom service registration
var appId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<int>("AppSettings:AppId");
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISomeService>(new SomeService(appId));

Configure options and validation
builder.Services
    .AddOptions<AssetsOptions>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(AssetsOptions.SectioName))
    .Validate(config => config.AppId > 0, "Option AppId must be configured in config section")
    .ValidateOnStart();

// You can now inject AssetsOptions anywhere in your app
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAnotherService, AnotherService>();

Use like this and put all together
var appId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<int>("AppSettings:AppId");

builder.Services
    .AddOptions<AssetsOptions>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(AssetsOptions.SectioName))
    .Validate(config => config.AppId > 0, "Option AppId must be configured in config section")
    .ValidateOnStart();

// Example: Register a service that uses the config value directly
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISomeService>(serviceProvider =>
{
    var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    var appId = config.GetValue<int>("AppSettings:AppId");
    return new SomeService(appId);
});


great solution, thanks!

Solution suggested by flackoverstow and works great.
I use a local version of AssetsOptions configures config as a service.
_ = builder.Services
    .AddOptions<AssetsOptions>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(AssetsOptions.SectioName))
    .Validate(config =>
    {
        return config.AppId > 0;
    }, "Option AppId must be configured in config section")
    .ValidateOnStart();

AssetsOptions config = new();
builder.Configuration.GetSection(AssetsOptions.SectioName).Bind(config);

